# Method .clean() of model not triggered when called from viewsets

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

APIView won't call method .clean() from model on "POST".

I have created a model 'Budget' and added an extra validation by overriding method .clean(). The clean is properly called when used in django admin. I have also created an APIView 'BudgetReportView' from this model, however the method .clean() is not called on method "POST".

I am looking for the best practice to solve this issue. Should I also add validation in my APIView or override method post and trigger .clean() ?

Thanks for the advice

(I didn't include code as it is just a question of best practice but I can add it if needed).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since version 3.1 Django-Rest-Framework doesn't call the model validation methods anymore out of the box, but you can call them manually inside a serializer's `validate()` method:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        instance = Model(**data)
        try:
            instance.clean()
        # Note that this raises Django's ValidationError Exception
        except ValidationError as e:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(e.args[0])
```

Comment: Actually it doesnt return all the error messages at once. 
It seems .validate() is called only if django built in field validations don't raise errors